# How to store tagged union in HDF5

Tags: hdf5, discriminated-union, union-types

Suppose I had a dataset like this (JSON):

```
items: [
  {
    type: "foo",
    foo_a: [1, 2, 3],
    foo_b: "Dave",
    foo_c: false
  },
  {
    type: "bar",
    bar_a: 4,
    bar_b: [false, true]
  },
  ...
]
```

In other words, I have an array of tagged unions. What is the best way to store this data in HDF5? As far as I can tell it doesn't [natively support unions](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc1.6/UG/11_Datatypes.html):

> HDF5 does not support datatypes with distinguished records or the equivalent of C unions

And the only other reference I've found to unions in HDF5 is in [a wishlist from 2007](ftp://gamma.hdfgroup.org/pub/outgoing/web/wishlist/wishlist.pdf):

> *Support for union (discriminated, variant, etc.) datatypes.*
>
> A union, or discriminated, datatype is one in which several different types can be stored in the same location. This is similar to the union datatype in C.
> A variant of this is the "tagged union" type in which a tag field indicates just what type is being represented in any given instance, so that the data element
> is handled correctly when the element is accessed. Unions can save storage by overlapping storage areas for each type, since only one is in use at a time.
> **There is a great deal of interest in this feature, but as yet we have not obtained the resources for it.**

How can I store this data? The only options I can think of are:

1. Store each variant in a separate dataset with references to them:

```
items: [
  {
    type: "foo",
    index: 0
  },
  {
    type: "bar",
    index: 0
  },
  ...
],
items_foo: [
  {
    foo_a: [1, 2, 3],
    foo_b: "Dave",
    foo_c: false
  },
  ...
],
items_bar: [
  {
    bar_a: 4,
    bar_b: [false, true]
  },
  ...
]
```

2. Include every possible field and use default values:

```
items: [
  {
    type: "foo",
    foo_a: [1, 2, 3],
    foo_b: "Dave",
    foo_c: false,

    bar_a: 0,
    bar_b: []
  },
  {
    type: "bar",
    bar_a: 4,
    bar_b: [false, true],

    foo_a: [],
    foo_b: "",
    foo_c: false
  },
  ...
]
```

3. Make the dataset an opaque blob type and use some encoding that does support tagged unions (e.g. JSON; though I obviously wouldn't use JSON).

All of those options suck (though I think the first options is probably the best & cleanest). Are there any better ways?

Comment: The HDF5 schema is built around Groups and Datasets, similar to a filesystem. Groups are like folders, and datasets are the data containers (files). Dataset data structure is analogous to NumPy arrays (ndarrays for homogeouous types, and recarrays for mixed types). Given these limitations, HDF5 is probably not the best file format for your needs.

Comment: I am aware of that. However most of my data is matrices, and I need a format that can be written to disk a bit at a time. HDF5 is one of the few formats that has good support for both of these, so I am evaluating it (actually it is the only format I've found so far). This is one of the sticking points, but if it can be solved in a not-too-ugly way then it might still be worth it.